# Custom Taxonomy breaking pages permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, filters, slug

I'm stuck for some days with this problem and I don't know what else to do.

With **`%somethingHere%`** on slug rewrite, pages permalinks are broken (CPT AND CT OK).

Without, I don't have my desired Post structure but Pages permalinks are OK.

#### CPT and CT Creation

```php
function custom_post_type() {

register_taxonomy(
    'marca',
    '',
    array(
        'label' => 'Marcas',
        'singular_label' => 'Marca',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true
        //'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'relogios'),
        )
    );


$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Relogios', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Relogio', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Relogios', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'relogios', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Relogios', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'post_tag' , 'marca'),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        //'slug' => 'event',
        'slug' => '%marca%/relogios',
        'with_front' => true
        ),
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-clock',
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
register_post_type( 'relogios', $args );


$labels_joias = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Joias', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Joia', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Joias', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
$args_joias = array(
    'label'               => __( 'joias', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Joias', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels_joias,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array('post_tag', 'marca' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => '%marca%/joias',
        'with_front' => true
        ),
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-clock',
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
register_post_type( 'joias', $args_joias );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type');
```

#### Post Link Filter

This is the function where I replace the general taxonomy name for the current taxonomy term.

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'marca_permalink_structure');
function marca_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    //if (is_page()) { return $post_link;}
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%marca%' ) ) {
        $event_type_term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'marca' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%marca%', array_pop( $event_type_term )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "broken"?  Permalink returns a 404 for pages only but not CPT or tax pages?

Comment: Exactly @jdm2112

Comment: Have your tried re-saving your permalinks in your settings? Sometimes this has helped me when I've had issues with permalinks. Also check for plugin conflicts.

Comment: the simplest fix is to prefix your structure with something static

Comment: @stemie yes, I always re-save my permalinks after changing some CPT or CT related thing

Comment: @Milo I know that if I keep my taxonomy name in the slug it works... But client wants without it

Comment: you'll either have to hook request parsing and somehow convert the requests to set the correct query vars, or disable rewrite in your post type registration and manually add the rewrite rules to handle your post types. also, always develop with [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), your code has some errors.

Comment: Hey change `'has_archive' => true` and then goto your admin settings->Permalinks and two times save the Permalink then i think it work fine

Comment: Did you ever find an answer here? I'm running into the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a link to your site and a little more explanation on what you are trying to achieve?

Here's a shot in the dark guess.

Archives shows content of type 'post', but you can alter it to include custom post types. Add this filter to your functions.php file:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
 if( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
  $query->set( 'post_type', array(
   'post', 'nav_menu_item', 'your-custom-post-type-here'
      ));
    return $query;
  }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your asking, but I couldn't figure out how to format the permalinks for my custom post type and found this plugin which gives you some options for easy customization

[Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)